# Click button expands the div horizontally by closing other two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Guys I am new to jQuery...please help me to learn this. I want to expand the div(#center) taking width:100% on click that in turn closes the other 2 divs (#left and #right) in my case.
Please someone help me to solve this. And the most imp thing is that the transition should be swift nd not at once. Reply is appreciated. And its not lyk i dint try it first. I tried using click function to make it happen..bt dint work as desired

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

#taskDetails {
 width: 900px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd;
}

#description {
 width: 900px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd;
}

#details {
 float: left;
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: auto;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
 display: inline-block;
}

#left {
 float: left;
 width: 250px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd; 
}

#center {
 width: 370px;
 float: left;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd; 
    margin-left: 9px;
}

#right {
 float: right;
 width: 250px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd; 
}

#head {
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 background: #8CBF26;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a {
 padding: 0 10px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background-color: #00ABA9;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.heading {
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="abc.css">
  <script href="abc.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

  <div id="main">

   <div id="taskDetails">

    <div id="head">
     <div class="heading">FORM</div>
    </div>

    <div id="formTab">

     <div id="form">
      
     </div>

    </div>

   </div>

   <div id="description">

    <div id="head">

     <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Tab 3</a></li>
     </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="content">

     <div class="rte">
     </div>

     <div class="text">
     </div>

    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="details">

    <div id="left">

     <div id="head">
      <div class="heading">Projects</div>
     </div>

     <div class="data">
     </div>

    </div>

    <div id="center">

     <div id="head">
      <div class="heading">Details</div>
     </div>

     <div class="data">
     </div>

    </div>

    <div id="right">

     <div id="head">
      <div class="heading">Tab 3</div>
     </div>

     <div class="data">
     </div>

    </div>

   </div>

  </div>

 </body>
```

Comment: There's no jQuery in the code you shared. Add it back into your code so we can see what you actually attempted.

Comment: Wht i tried is juz basic since i have no idea on how to collapse the div wen adjacent...plz give a link 2 ans or write d code(juz jquery function)

Comment: Since there's no actual import of the JQuery library in the HTML, I would like to ask: Are you sure this is a JQuery question? Or, is this simply a term being (incorrectly) interchanged with "JavaScript"? You might get answers that won't help you if people believe you're using JQuery, when you're not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example for "tab2"

```
$("#tab2").click(function () {
    $("#center").css("width", "100%");
    $("#left").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#right").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u87z1m3n/1/

And put id's to the li's in order to be able to select them:

```
<li id="tab1"><a href="#home">Tab 1</a>
</li>
<li id="tab2"><a href="#news">Tab 2</a>
</li>
<li id="tab3"><a href="#contact">Tab 3</a>
</li>
```

The example is very coarse as the code needs a lot more refining...
But I think that it gives an answer to your question...

Answer (score 0):

Study the example below. Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
$("#head li").click(function () {
    $("#center, #left, #right").eq($(this).index()).css("width", "100%");
    $("#center, #left, #right").not($(this)).hide();

});
```

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.current {
  width: 100%
    }
#taskDetails {
 width: 900px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd;
}

#description {
 width: 900px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd;
}

#details {
 float: left;
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: auto;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
 display: inline-block;
}

#left {
 float: left;
 width: 250px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd; 
}

#center {
 width: 370px;
 float: left;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: red; 
    margin-left: 9px;
}

#right {
 float: right;
 width: 250px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd; 
}

#head {
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 background: #8CBF26;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a {
 padding: 0 10px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background-color: #00ABA9;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.heading {
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">

   <div id="taskDetails">

    <div id="head">
     <div class="heading">FORM</div>
    </div>

    <div id="formTab">

     <div id="form">
      
     </div>

    </div>

   </div>

   <div id="description">

    <div id="head">

     <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Tab 3</a></li>
     </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="content">

     <div class="rte">
     </div>

     <div class="text">
     </div>

    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="details">

    <div id="left">

     <div id="head">
      <div class="heading">Projects</div>
     </div>

     <div class="data">
     </div>

    </div>

    <div id="center">

     <div id="head">
      <div class="heading">Details</div>
     </div>

     <div class="data">
     </div>

    </div>

    <div id="right">

     <div id="head">
      <div class="heading">Tab 3</div>
     </div>

     <div class="data">
     </div>

    </div>

   </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/JoKZBJ)** showing the final result of everything below. Please read it carefully so you can learn the process and understand everything that's happening.

---

First of all, your HTML needed a lot of cleanup. You called `head` as an ID, but used it multiple times throughout your code. If you're going to use a selector more than once, it should be a class instead. I changed it in the HTML and the CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="taskDetails">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="heading">FORM</div>
    </div>
        <div id="formTab">
            <div id="form"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="description">
        <div class="head">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#news">Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Tab 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="rte"></div>
            <div class="text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="details">
        <div id="left">
            <div class="head">
               <div class="heading">Projects</div>
            </div>
               <div class="data"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
            <div class="head">
               <div class="heading">Details</div>
            </div>
            <div class="data"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="heading">Tab 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="data"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Next, in your CSS, you hadn't set the widths of your containers correctly, so adding something like `width:100%` wasn't doing anything because there was no max width to fill. I added that to your styles. Remember, I also updated the markup from changing your `head` id to a class.

Additionally, I removed the floats from you `left`,`right`, and `center` divs because that removes the blocks from the flow of the document, which can lead to funny behavior. Instead, I changed them to `display:inline-block` and set their widths relative to the container.

Finally, I added a `.wide` class at the end which will set the width of the `center` div.

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#main {
  width:100%;
}
#taskDetails {
  width:auto;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd;
}
#description {
  width:auto;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd;
}
#details {
  width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    display: inline-block;
}
#left {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:20%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd;    
}
#center {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:50%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: red;    
}
#right {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:20%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    background: #dddddd;    
}
.head {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #8CBF26;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
a {
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background-color: #00ABA9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.heading {
    padding: 5px;
}
.wide {
  width:100% !important;
  transition:.5s;
}
```

Now, this can be done with jQuery, so make sure you add the script in the `head` of your HTML.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The jQuery script is pretty simple, and does three things:
  1. When you click on any of the tab buttons, it will hide the `#left` and `#right` divs.
  2. The `#center` div expands to 100% of the container.
  3. When you click on the tab again, it will shrink the `#center` div and bring the other two back.

**jQuery**

```
$(".head ul li").click(function() {
  $("#left, #right").animate({width:"toggle"});
  $("#center").toggleClass('wide');
})
```

I used `toggle` in both of the calls because it gives a fairly nice animation without making you code in specifics. It also handles adding or removing a class, so your script can stay simple if all you want to do is add or remove that class with each click.

If you want something more complex, you'll definitely want to look at JavaScript instead of jQuery as @Katana314 mentioned above. They're for two different things, so make sure you understand the difference between the two.